# How can i get metadata for dataset objects in salesforce wave analytics?

Tags: metadata, einstein-analytics

I m trying to find a way in salesforce wave analytics to get the metadata of dataset object dynamically. Since user have a flexibility to choose either Salesforce objects or to upload a CSV file to create a dataset, extracting the fields is difficult. So i am trying to get a way to somehow extract the fields used by user dynamically. Can this be achieved in salesforce wave analytics using any REST API?